# Why is this an infinite loop...? I don't understand

Tags: python

```py
#import time

annual_salary = int(input("Enter your annual salary: "))
monthly_salary = annual_salary / 12
#print(monthly_salary)

portion_saved = float(input("Enter the percent of your salary to save, as a decimal: "))
monthly_saved = monthly_salary * portion_saved
#print(monthly_saved)

total_cost = int(input("Enter the cost of your dream home: "))
portion_down_payment = total_cost * 0.25
#print(portion_down_payment)

current_savings = 0

number_of_months = 0

while current_savings < portion_down_payment:
    #time.sleep(1)
    current_savings *= 0.04/12
    current_savings += monthly_saved
    number_of_months += 1
    print(current_savings, number_of_months)

print("Number of months:", number_of_months)
```

Result:

```
Enter your annual salary: 120000
Enter the percent of your salary to save, as a decimal: .10
Enter the cost of your dream home: 1000000
1000.0 1
1003.3333333333334 2
1003.3444444444444 3
1003.3444814814815 4
1003.3444816049383 5
1003.3444816053498 6
1003.3444816053511 7
1003.3444816053511 8
1003.3444816053511 9
1003.3444816053511 10
1003.3444816053511 11
1003.3444816053511 12
1003.3444816053511 13
1003.3444816053511 14
1003.3444816053511 15
1003.3444816053511 16
# Manually Terminated
```

What is wrong with this code??? I'm so confused... probably something dumb. a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z

Comment: What's with the alphabet at the end?

Comment: it tells me to add more details because the question body is mostly code. Sorry, I am new to the forum :\

Comment: OK, it's telling you that for a reason. Please make a [mre], instead of copy-pasting your entire script. To start, get rid of the `time` comments, replace the `input`s with static data, (`annual_salary = 120000`, etc), and you don't need 16 months of output when say, 5 will do. BTW, welcome to SO! Please take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: Moderator, you may delete this question now if you can. It's a bad question, and I think this is not useful to anyone else.

Comment: @AnthonyDu. you have the ability to close the question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
current_savings *= 0.04/12
```

You're multiplying current_savings by 0.00333333333333333333333333333333 every loop.

If you start with 1:
current_savings wlll equal 1 * 0.00333333333333333333333333333333

Again second loop it will get even smaller. You're making current_savings 3% of it's value, it will never be larger than the portion_down_payment

Comment: Fix is making it `current_savings *= 1 + 0.04/12` to make it accrue interest, not *reduce* it to just the interest on the previous balance.

Comment: Correct! Thanks ShadowRanger, I didn't really go over it enough to determine what they were trying to achieve, just to explain where the error was. Kudos!